# How to place search icon to the left of the input box

Tags: javascript, html, css

i wanted to place clear icon to the left most of the input. so that user need not to go to other side of the input as input will cover whole screen.

**i'm expecting my output something like below one:**

[image]

**currently i'm using below code:**

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="please write something to see">
```

Comment: So what have you tried? We're not a code-writing service.

Comment: see example here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_form_icon.asp

Comment: @smart-googler,i want to use default one, so that i can avoid clearing `input` in `javascript` (**i meant javascript code writing manually**)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
 <p><i class="classofthex" onclick="document.GetelementById('in1').innerText = ''; " ></i><input id="in1" type="text" placeholder="please write something to see"></p>
```

you can find the x icon in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Go through this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_anim_search)

It should be clear from the following:
You use two css properties on:

```
input[type=text]{
background-image: url('/url')
backgroung-repeat: no-repeat
}
```